# What is non-blocking generator

Tags: python, generator, nonblocking, coroutine

This excerpt is from Python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). It the doc string says the function is `non-blocking`(e.g.# non-blocking dict iterator), that is where I don't understand .

```
def iter_except(func, exception, first=None):
    """ Call a function repeatedly until an exception is raised.

    Converts a call-until-exception interface to an iterator interface.
    Like builtins.iter(func, sentinel) but uses an exception instead
    of a sentinel to end the loop.

    Examples:
        iter_except(functools.partial(heappop, h), IndexError)   # priority queue iterator
        iter_except(d.popitem, KeyError)                         # non-blocking dict iterator
        iter_except(d.popleft, IndexError)                       # non-blocking deque iterator
        iter_except(q.get_nowait, Queue.Empty)                   # loop over a producer Queue
        iter_except(s.pop, KeyError)                             # non-blocking set iterator

    """
    try:
        if first is not None:
            yield first()            # For database APIs needing an initial cast to db.first()
        while 1:
            yield func()
    except exception:
        pass
```

It appears to me is just a `generator function` doing the same thing as `iter()`.

As far as I know, `non-blocking` means async or parallel computing, or when you get rid off the `lock` at multi-thread .
The snippet is in synchronous execution. What is `non-blocking` here meant?

Comment: I suppose they mean that `d` can be changed during iteration by other code, so this function doesn't 'block' it. Using `iter` and changing underlaying container can cause unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it - the `non-blocking` here is used as `not breaking the code execution when a specific error occurs`.

So these generators don't 'block' my code from running when the exception occurs.